# Authorization annotations in Go GRPC

Tags: go, annotations, authorization, grpc, grpc-go

I have a GRPC server with APIs that are authorized like:

```
func (s *MyServer) MyAPI(ctx context.Context, req MyAPIRequest) (MyAPIResponse, error) {
  isAuthorized, err = s.IsAuthorized(ctx, req.UserId, Role.User) // other APIs may use a different authorization function than IsAuthorized
  if err != nil {
    return nil, err
  }
  
  if !isAuthorized {
    return nil,  status.Error(codes.PermissionDenied, "not authorized")
  }

  // rest of API code
}
```

I'd like to know how to:

1. Simplify usage of the authorization logic, like an annotation. I'm more familiar with Java where it would be like `@Authorize(ctx = ctx, req = req, role = Role.User)` above the func.
2. Require authorization checks for APIs, so that builds fail if at least one API is missing authorization. I'm using bazel. Note that not all `func (s *MyServer)` will be APIs.

Here's my idea:

1. .

   - Create a YAML file with key value pairs of method name to authorization rule. Example is `MyAPI: IsUserIdAuthorizedAsUser` which would translate to `s.IsAuthorized(ctx, req.UserId, Role.User)`.
   - Create an interceptor that looks up authz rule for the request's method name and calls the corresponding authz function.
2. Have a bazel build rule that parses proto files for `rpc`, which are all the API method names, and fails if not all of them are in the rule list. I don't know how to do this yet.

Would appreciate any suggestions on my idea or better ways.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an interceptor (grpc.UnaryInterceptor) to handle the authentication / authorization  process. It is similar to the classic spring filter (java world).

You can read about interceptors here: https://shijuvar.medium.com/writing-grpc-interceptors-in-go-bf3e7671fe48

You can easily chain multi interceptors or having interceptor per grpc method.

This below is an interceptor that I wrote some months ago (it uses JWT as auth mechanism). You can use it as example:

```
func (jwt JwtInterceptor) Interceptor(
   ctx context.Context,
   req interface{},
   info *grpc.UnaryServerInfo,
   handler grpc.UnaryHandler) (interface{}, error) {

    md, _ := metadata.FromIncomingContext(ctx)

    token := md["jwt"]

    if token == nil {
        return nil, errors.New("token not present")
    }

   apiClaims, err := jwt.decoder.Parse(token[0])
   if err != nil {
     return nil, errors.New("token signature not valid")
   }

   return handler(context.WithValue(ctx, "jwt", apiClaims), req)
 }
```